# Scroll в MasterDetailPage Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Есть такой код:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Menu" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="5,0,5,0">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Image WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Blue" Source="" />
                    <Button BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" Text="text" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Image WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Blue" Source="" />
                    <Button BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" Text="text" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
                    ...
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Но из-за количества элементов они не помещаются на экране. Каким образом можно добавить скролл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прокрутку элементов в xamarin обеспечивает StackLayout и ScrollView.
Вот ссылка на эту тему:https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/3.2.php

Comment: Спасибо, у меня ещё такой вопрос: при прокрутке справа появляется плашка, показывающая, на сколько прокручен ScrollView. Как её можно скрыть?

Comment: @QIMZ Над объявлением пространства имен помещает эту строку:

`[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ScrollView), typeof(ScrollViewExRenderer))]`

Теперь ваш `ScrollView` не должен показывать полосы прокрутки

Comment: К сожалению, Visual Studio не может найти пространство имён, в котором находится ExportRenderer, ScrollViewExRenderer

Comment: @QIMZ просто введите в поисковик:"Как скрыть полосу прокрутки ScrollVeiw xamarin".Первая ссылка второй ответ.Я не могу вас дать ссылку на сайт так-как этот портал мне запрещает это делать.Сайт на котором ответ входит  как спам сайт.